# C seg fault in bubble sort variation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bubble-sort

My code is as follows:

```
  void bubbleSort(char *array, int size){
   int sorted = 0;
   int x;
   while(!sorted){
      int start = 0; 
      int stop = size; 

    sorted = 1;
    for(x = start; x < stop; x++){
        if(array[x] > array[x+1]){
            swap(array[x], array[x+1]);
            sorted = 0;
        }
    }
    if(sorted){
        break;
    }
    sorted = 1;
    for(x = stop; x > start; x--){
        if(array[x-1] > array[x]){
            swap(array[x], array[x-1]);
            sorted = 0;
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

and based off the algorithm:

```
 sorted = false
 while (!sorted){

  start = start element of sublist.
  stop = stop element of sublist.

  sorted = true
  for (x = start; x < stop  ; x++){
     if Numbers[x] > Numbers[x+1]{
        swap(Numbers[x], Numbers[x+1]);
        sorted = false;
     }
  }

  if (sorted) break;

  sorted = true
  for (x = stop; x > start ; x--){
     if Numbers[x-1] > Numbers[x]{
        swap(Numbers[x], Numbers[x-1]);
        sorted = false;
     }
  }
}
```

This is a variation of classic bubblesort in that the full list is processed each time and the sort is performed in both directions.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does, it's just giving you the size of a pointer. You need to pass the array size as a separate parameter. Also, the line that computes `stop` should probably end with `-1` instead of `+1`.

Comment: Hm. Other examples I've viewed found the length of an array via "(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))". I have no problem passing in the size of the array as parameter however how to compute the size outside of the function if not using the previously noted method

Comment: Can we use `if` condition without this. `()`. ?????

Comment: Yes, if you declare `char array[100]` and do `sizeof(array)` in the same function, you'll get 100, but if you pass the array to a subroutine, you lose the size information.  You can confirm this with `printf`.

Comment: A search for `[c] sizeof array` will give you some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sizeof` to get the size of array is tricky in C, that it only gives you the right answer when applied to the original array. For example,

```
int array[10];
int len = sizeof(array); // => 10 * sizeof(int)
```

However when applied to a pointer, as you did in your `bubbleSort` function, it only gives the size of an `int` pointer. You'll have to pass the size of the array along with the pointer to your function.